# regex match combined with something before a string if exists

Tags: regex

I tried to get the sub-strings from a string
such like:

test strings:

```
cat_zoo_New_York_US
dog_zoo_South_Carolina
dolphin_zoo_Montreal_Canada
pokemon_home_d_K2-155
```

returned sub strings:

```
cat, New_York
dog, South_Carolina
dolphin, Montreal
pokemon, d
```

the Regex pattern I have tried is

```
([\w]+)(?:(_zoo_|_home_))(((?!(_US|_Canada|_K2-155))\w)+)
```

which I don't think is very concise and it returns other sub-strings besides what I need. Do you have any other suggestions?
Thanks!

---

### Some updates

after @The fourth bird's answer  @03/15/2018.

First of all, I like the idea of utilizing both `([^_]+)` and the `(?:)` for different part of the sample strings.But let me extend a little more of the sample strings.

```
cat_zoo_New_York_US
dog_zoo_South_Carolina
yellow_dolphin_zoo_Montreal_Canada
pokemon_home_d_K2-155
pokemon_home_zoo_d_K2-155
```

I actually want to use the anchor strings such as 'zoo','home' or 'home_zoo' to separate the characters before and after, together with matching(and discarding) the last part of the country(or whatever specified place ID), which makes this question a bit less general(I like the idea of using `_`,but let me make it more tricky to learn better).
two questions here

1. what is the function of `(?=)` and `.*` here in
   `(?=(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$)).*$`? It seems if I use
   `(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$)`, it is still ok...
2. since I extended a little bit on the anchor string to let it support
   `_`, I used:

   `(.*?)(?:_*)(?:home_zoo|zoo|home)(?:_*)(.*?)(?:_*)(?:US|Canada|K2-155|$)`

   It seems ok, but if I use:

   `(.*?)(?:_*)(?:home|zoo|home_zoo)(?:_*)(.*?)(?:_*)(?:US|Canada|K2-155|$)`

   It will firstly match `home` for the last sample string. Is there a
   greedy algorithm to catch this without specify the order of the pattern
   string?

Well again, I don't like to make a long list of anchor strings, but I don't have other ideas make it more general without doing so.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it like this:

[`^([^_]+)_[^_]+_(.*?)(?=(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$)).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/yyONkQ/1)

This will capture 2 groups. You could for example use this in a replacement with `group1, group2`.

First capture the first part ending on an underscore in group 1 like `cat_`. Then match the second part ending with an underscore like `zoo_` or `home_`.

From that point capture in a group until you encounter one of your values using a lookahead `(?=` or the end of the string.

That would match:

- `^` Begin of the string
- `([^_]+)` Match in a capturing group not an _ one or more times **(group 1)**
- `_[^_]+_` match _ then not an _ one or more times followed by _
- `(.*?)` Capture in a group any character zero or more times greedy **(group 2)**
- `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts what is on the right side is

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$` your values or end of the string
  - `)` Close group
- `)` Close group
- `.*$` Match any character zero or more times till the end of the string

**Edit**: After the updated question, perhaps this will suit your requirements:

[`^(.*?)_(?:home_zoo|zoo|home)(.*?)(?=(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/yQNBJG/1)

This will match any charcter zero or more times non greedy `(.*?)`, then an underscore and a non capturing group `(?:home|zoo|home_zoo)` to separate the characters before and after.

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird, would you please explain a little bit on how to understand the part (.*?)(?=(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$)).*

Comment: @georgeandrew I have added an explanation of the match.

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird, I have some further questions updated in my original question, since it's a bit inconvenient to do so in the comments.

Comment: @georgeandrew You can certainly use `^([^_]+)_[^_]+_(.*?)(?=(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$))` without the `.*$`. I have added that part in case you want to use a replace method. If you use replace and do not match that part then that part will still be there [after the replacement](https://regex101.com/r/yyONkQ/3). The `(?=` means a positive lookahead. You match any character in a capturing group `(.*?)` until you encounter one of these values `(?=(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$))`.

Comment: Thank you@The fourth bird, but still, for (?:home_zoo|zoo|home), the result depends on the sequence of the key words; and what is the function of (?=) in  (?=(?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$))--seems only (?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155|$) will work?. Thanks and have a good weekend.

Comment: Thank you@The fourth bird, I haven't carefully noticed your explanation about `(?=`, and I understand this now. So now the only question is how to make it sequence independently for  `(?:home_zoo|zoo|home) `

Comment: @georgeandrew Right now this matches using an alternation in a non capturing group because the whole string uses an underscore between all words. You want to use `home_zoo`, `zoo` and `home` to separate the characters before and after. Because you have `home_zoo` and `home` I list the longest match at the left. You could read this page about [`alternation`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: Thank you very much again@The fourth bird,it's a very nice tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried a more straightforward approach. If your data is more complex than the sample that you gave above, this may fail. Otherwise, for the above text, it works fine.

Here is the expression that I used:

```
^([^_]*)_[^_]*_(.*)_.*$
1       23    45   67
```

Basically what I did was:

1. Group the first char stream, which does not contain _, starting at the beginning of the line.
2. Then there is an _ following the above group
3. Follows an arbitrary length string, which does not have _'s in it
4. Then comes an _
5. Group the next arbitrary length string
6. Comes and _ afterwards
7. Rest of the string

replace it with \1, \2 (first group, second group).

You can find a fiddle [here](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/272)

If you are using vim, you can also achieve the same thing in vim with the following command:

```
:%s/^[^_]*_\([^_]*\)_\(.*\)_.*$/\1, \2/g
```

**UPDATE**

```
^([^_]*)_[^_]*_(((?:South_)|(?:New_))*[^_]*)((?:_US)|(?:_Canada)|(?:_K2-155))*$
```

You can find the new fiddle (here)[https://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/273]

What is the difference between this one and the previous one?

Now, I cheat a little, as such that I look for adjectives, which modify the state name, like South_ or New_. You can add more here, like East_, West_, Old_ or whatever if there is a case in your date.

There are cases where country is skipped in data. Plus looks like that last token on the very last line does not follow up a pattern. So, I explicitly listed those options in the expression, like US, Canada etc. You may need to add more exceptional cases in here as well.

Comment: Thank you @Alp, it's a good idea...but it cannot distinguish the last group after '_' is a certain string in the list that I need to exclude. For example the 2nd case, it will return 'South' instead of 'South_Carolina'

Comment: Thank you @Alp, I like your idea using '_' to split and actually pointed out (?:_US)|(?:_Canada)|(?:_K2-155) has the same function to (?:_US|_Canada|_K2-155)